# How to access all Bootstrap SASS variables with Laravel Mix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, sass

I see that I can access all Boostrap 3 LESS variables, per https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

I am using Laravel 5.5 and mix, which in turn uses SASS.  How can I get access to to the same number of variables that are available under the LESS implementation?

Comment: You still have access to the same variables

Comment: @samrap, you should post an answer based on this.  It was simple, and obvious in hindsight, but really helpful at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap Sass is built in the same way as the Less implementation in that the same variables are available and can be modified to tweak the framework. Nothing else needed to get this working! It's also worth noting that Bootstrap 4 is in beta and is built on Sass natively.